# Why My total sum is not coming in my editableTableWidget plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I am trying to make a table with `editableTableWidget` plugin like Remark Theme but here is not showing the total sum of column in the last row.

[image]

```
<table id="mainTable" class=" table table-striped table-bordered text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Year 1</th>
            <th>Year 2</th>
            <th>Year 3</th>
            <th>Year 4</th>
            <th>Year 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Retail Price</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Retail Quantity</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Affiliate Price</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Affiliate Quantity</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Whole Prize</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Whole Quantity</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Custom Prize</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Custom Quantity</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit Cost</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
            <td>1780</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>TOTAL</strong></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mainTable').editableTableWidget()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am using latest version of editableTableWidget because, i can not find cdn that's why i did't enter patch of editableTableWidget.js

Comment: Where did you include the file editableTableWidget.js in your code?

Comment: after jquery script and before my custom script

Comment: Where is your logic / JS for creating these 'sum' cells? You have to do that yourself, editableTableWidget doesn't do any summing or auto-filling.